# Python - buildung an Index

Tags: python

I am a beginner in Python and in order to construct an Index for Books, I have to write a function in Python which have to return a String. As parameter the function have to take a List. 
FOr instance my PageIndex could take this form: [1,2,3,4,12]. The returned String should take this Form: '1-4,12'.
Here, the dash replace the numbers between 1 and 4 and a coma should separate the chapters which not follow the numeral sequence.
An other sequence : [0,2,3,4,569].
THanks for any tips!
BeBop

Comment: Some code with a more specific question, please?

Comment: "and what have you tried so far?"

Comment: tried asking stackoverflow ;)

Comment: There should be a "We're not going to do your homework for you" closing reason (good idea, but not mine... I just read it here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/22918413/289011)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
import itertools

def ranges(i):
    for a, b in itertools.groupby(enumerate(i), lambda (x, y): y - x):
        b = list(b)
        yield b[0][1], b[-1][1]

print(list(ranges([1, 2, 3, 4, 12])))
```

**Output:**

```
[[1, 4], 12]
```